# Inventory detail To Bins column

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I'm trying to create a user event script so that I can read the values (To Bins) inside the inventory detail subrecord for every line. Have something like this:-

```
var invt=nlapiLoadRecord('inventorytransfer', 123222);
invt.selectLineItem('item', 1);
var invDetailSubrecord = invt.viewCurrentLineItemSubrecord('item', 'inventorydetail');
invDetailSubrecord.selectLineItem('inventoryassignment', 1);
var invnum = invDetailSubrecord.getCurrentLineItemValue('inventoryassignment', 'inventorynumber')
nlapiLogExecution('debug', invnum, '', '');
```

But I got an error. I'm also not sure what is the exact field name for 'To Bins' column. Am I missing something?

Comment: can you add some more context to it. Its not clear what you want to pull and from where ? There is no such `To Bins` column in `inventorytransfer` record type.

Comment: What error are you getting, please? Difficult to test because our system doesn't have advanced bin/ inventory management enabled, but unless the inventory transfer record is very different after that you can access to bin like this                                                                                 var invt = nlapiLoadRecord("inventorytransfer", 123222);
var bin = invt.getLineItemValue('inventory','tobinnumbers',1);

Comment: it has been confirmed with NS that the inventory detail subrecord under inventory transfers are non scriptable.